# How to correctly implement properties in complex objects

Tags: java, class, javafx, properties

I have the following models:

```
class IdNamePair
{
    protected int id;
    protected String name;

    public IdNamePair()
    {
        id = 0;
        name = "";
    }
}

class Voyage extends IdNamePair
{
    //Several string and int variables
}

class Employee extends IdNamePair
{
    //Several string and int variables
}

class Vessel extends IdNamePair
{
    //Some string and int variables
}

class Details
{
    //Several string and int variables
}

class Summary
{
    protected Vessel vessel;
    protected Employee chief;
    protected Employee operator;
    protected List<Details> details
}

class Update
{
    protected LocalDateTime created;
    protected LocalDateTime modified;
    List<Summary> summaries;
    //Some string and int variable.
}
```

I fail to understand how to create a complex Object with several Lists, Maps and instances of other classes. I can replace existing types of fields with corresponding property types (`String` to `StringProperty`, `double` to `DoubleProperty`, etc.) but how do I handle complex types (`List<Summary>`, `HashMap<String, Vessel>`, `List<Details>`)?

The other question is if I want to support properties, should I convert existing objects or do I need to create new ones. I can replace

```
class IdNamePair
{
    protected int id;
    protected String name;
}
```

with

```
class IdNamePair
{
    protected IntegerProperty id;
    protected StringProperty name;
}
```

or I can provide a new type

```
class IdNamePairEx
{
    protected IntegerProperty id;
    protected StringProperty name;

    public IdNamePairEx(IdNamePair idNamePair);

    ///to simple object
    public IdNamePair toIdNamePair();
    ///from simple object
    public void fromIdNamePair(IdNamePair idNamePair);
}
```

and use it when dealing with GUI code. This approach would provide backward compatibility with existing code (JSON serialization, JDBC) but would effectively double the amount of my model classes. What is a preferred way?

**Update:**

I have a program that communicates to PostgreSQL and executes various CRUD operations. Corresponding classes exist for each table in the database.
I need to develop a new module that would make use of existing classes and I would like to implement GUI updates via bindings and properties.
Do I need to replace each type of variable with it's corresponding property type (`String` -> `StringProperty`) or is it better to create similar classes that operate via properties and provide conversion methods (`class Vessel` -> `class VesselWithPropertiesInteadOfRawTypes`)?

Comment: Have a look on `ObservableList`([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)) and `ObservableMap` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableMap.html))

Comment: "*What is a preferred way?*" For what? What is the context? How are those classes used? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If these classes are used as a model for GUI (view/controller) then you should use properties. Which and how? We can't know because you aren't telling us anything about that. Are the classes in the first code block database entities? Also, extending `IdNamePair` seems like bad design. What are the requirements for all the classes?

Comment: Use @username to ping users in comments.